# how do I handle dots (decimal points) in python parsley?

Tags: python, python-parsley

I'm trying to parse the output of a linux ps fuxa output using the following code (I started with {3} for testing purposes and I realized the parsing was failing due to the decimal point. My objective is to find THE_PACKAGE):

```
import parsley

x = parsley.makeGrammar("""                                                                                                                            
anything_followed_by_a_space = <anything+> ws                                                                                                          
rpm = anything_followed_by_a_space{3} <anything+>:name_of_the_rpm -> (name_of_the_rpm)                                                                 
""", {})
print x("root     26250  0.0  0.0 108208  1380 ?        S    16:01   0:00                      \_ sh /opt/scripts/V1.0/utils/install.sh THE_PACKAGE").rpm()
```

the letterOrDigit approach is not working when it finds `0.0`.

e.g.

```
root     26250  0.0  0.0 108208  1380 ?        S    16:01   0:00 ...
```

the `anything` built-in rule doesn't work either, I'm getting this error:

```
Parse error at line 2, column 0: end of input. trail: [anything]
```

any ideas?

-- UPDATE --

I managed to make it work like this but it looks ugly, I wish I could simplify all the special-character-check with the `anything` rule:

```
x = parsley.makeGrammar("""
a_dot = exactly('.')
a_colon = exactly(':')
a_question_mark = exactly('?') ws
the_activation_engine_script = '\_ sh /opt/scripts/V1.0/utils/install.sh'
anything_followed_by_a_space = <letterOrDigit+> ws|a_dot|a_question_mark|a_colon
rpm = anything_followed_by_a_space{18} the_activation_engine_script ws <anything+>:name_of_the_rpm -> (name_of_the_rpm)
""", {})
print x("root     26250  0.0  0.0 108208  1380 ?        S    16:01   0:00                      \_ sh /opt/scripts/V1.0/utils/install.sh THE_PACKAGE").rpm()
```

The output:

```
>>> 
THE_PACKAGE
```

Comment: What code are you using when you get that parse error?

Comment: Just edited the question to include the code, I'm pretty sure there's a more elegant way to achieve this without specifying the repetition of sections and whitespaces, but the "anything" rule is not working for some reason.